# Equation of line in 3-space that has no z-intercept

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering what the equation of a line would look like if the line had no z-intercept (e.g. parallel to the yz plane)?

This is because I have two lines in 3-space, given by their slope and intercept, one is in the xz plane, the other in the x=20,z plane (I hope that makes sense), and I'm trying to find the equation of the plane.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

P.S.

The equations are:
Line 1: $$z=2.51y + 0.987$$ and x is always equal to 20
Line 2: $$z=-0.00078x + 1.003$$ and y is always equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

Take the line: $L = \{(3,t,0): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and more generally, the form of such a line is:

$x = a, a \neq 0$, $y = t, t \in \mathbb{R}$, and $z = 0$.

Comment: It's not a line...